# dwc3_interrupt is getting called only once after usb cable connected to host pc

Tags: linux-device-driver

dwc3_interrupt is getting called only once after USB cable connected to host pc.
But as per the working scenario, it should be called multiple times before the USB device is enumerated on host pc.

Logs snapshot from DWC3 driver from the device side

> `[   78.649699] HH ---> inside dwc3_interrupt :1001
>   [   78.654704] HH ---> Inside dwc3_bh_work to call dwc3_thread_interrupt
>   [   78.661598] HH ---> Inside dwc3_process_event_buf to call dwc3_process_event_entry :4
>   [   78.669837] HH ---> Inside dwc3_process_event_entry to call dwc3_endpoint_interrupt vbus_active :1 pullups_connected: 1 is_devspec :1
>   [   78.682263] HH ---> Inside dwc3_process_event_entry :0
>   [   78.687786] HH ---> Inside dwc3_gadget_interrupt event->type :1
>   [   78.694115] dwc3 a600000.dwc3: HH ---> Notify OTG from dwc3_gadget_reset_interrupt
>   [   78.702094] msm-dwc3 a600000.ssusb: DWC3_CONTROLLER_NOTIFY_OTG_EVENT received
>   [   78.709292] HH ---> inside core usb_gadget_vbus_draw and mA :100
>   [   78.715692] dwc3 a600000.dwc3: [HH]---> dwc3_gadget_vbus_draw Notify controller from dwc3_gadget_vbus_draw. mA = 100
>   [   78.726643] msm-dwc3 a600000.ssusb: DWC3_CONTROLLER_SET_CURRENT_DRAW_EVENT received
>   [   78.734508] msm-dwc3 a600000.ssusb: HH ---> Avail curr from USB = 100`

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: *...it should be called multiple times...* Why do you think so?

Comment: I compared logs with reference HW where usb works ok and that says it should be called multiple times.